# Reduce method on mutiple selection in D3 v4

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm not able to make the `reduce` method working id D3 v4. I get `reduce is not a function` error. What's wrong?

```
var svg = d3.select('svg');

var dataSet = [10, 20, 30, 40];

var circle = svg.selectAll('circle')
    .data(dataSet)
    .enter()
    .append('circle')
    .attr("r",function(d){ return d })
    .attr("cx", function(d, i){ return i * 100 + 50 })
    .attr("cy",50)
    .attr("fill",'red')
   ;

var t=circle.reduce((total, circle) => total + circle.cx);
console.log(t)
```

Comment: what type is `circle`?

Comment: Selections were arrays prior to D3 *v3* but are plain object as of *v4*. Obviously, there is no method `.reduce()` on `Object`. Related: [*"D3 v4 - Accessing selection array and find corresponding element"*](/q/38702831).

Comment: The following should yield the desired result: `var t = d3.sum(circle.nodes(), n => n.cx.baseVal.value)`.

Comment: Just some nitpicking: given the code you provided and putting some basic algebra to use this can be rewritten as simple as `var t = 50 * dataSet.length ** 2;`.